# cfml, database and a multilingual website

Tags: coldfusion, multilingual, cfquery

I have a database that has four columns `id`,`languageid`,`name`,`text`

Depending on the users' default language, I create a query that has all the texts for the set language (`where languageid=#user.defaultlanguageid#`)

What's the easiest way of retrieving these when it comes to displaying the required string.

Seems like creating a subquery every time is a bit much work.

Is creating a function the best way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just have a single query that populates a struct (perhaps an application-level struct)  - something like this:

```
<cfif not IsDefined("application.langMap")>

<cfquery name="langNames" datasource="...">SELECT * from langTable</cfquery>

<cfset application.langMap = {}>
<cfloop query="langNames">
   <cfif not StructKeyExists(application.langMap, languageid)>
       <cfset application.langMap[languageid] = {}>
   </cfif>
   <cfset application.langMap[languageid][name] = text>
</cfloop>

</cfif>
```

And then as you need the particular string within the display:

```
#application.langMap[mylanguageid][name]#
```

Comment: I ended up creating a function, but your code helped heaps. Thanks